# Correct way to squash several commits

Tags: git, github

In my commit history top commits look like so:

```
1ccb0058e833d9765a3a1de2816fd408dde82305 Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/...
d462898e3a1dbd979b38bcec6d45991da0bca1e7 Add one cool feature
7e2f382e89448b7239b45f73f3b5be360435a0e6 Fix code styles
ce6b7f9ce11e06347e05aec4bfb21fea6b3b5b37 Add one cool feature
```

I want to combine `Add one cool feature`, `Fix code styles` and `Add one cool feature` into one commit and then merge back to master branch. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean *"correct"*? Have you tried something? What was the problem with it?

Comment: I tried `git reset --soft HEAD~4` and merging back, but got error messages

Comment: Why that command? What do you mean *"merging back"*? What error messages? [Edit] the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Squash my last X commits together using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `git rebase -i HEAD~4` and change `pick` to `f` (or `s`) on the commits you would like to squash. Then you have to force push.

Comment: I did it with `git reset --soft HEAD~4` and pushed with `--force`. Now I see, than one extra commit was squashed. So, it seems like instead of `HEAD~4`, it should be `HEAD~3`, but how can I revert history?

Comment: Just with rebase again, you can use `d`(for drop) to remove that commit again

Comment: Try `git reset --hard 1ccb0058e833d9765a3a1de2816fd408dde82305 ` and see if that works (top most hash from your question)